# SVN: Is there a way to copy to a branch all the latest revisions of the files committed under a revision, but only of those files?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I've read the entire "SVN book" but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Suppose I have trunk and branch_test, and the letters represent files commited:

Since with 1 reputation I can't post an image, here is an ASCII drawing:

```
Files: (A, B, C, E, R, Z)

     Z      R
     B      E
     A   C  A   C
  9  10  11 12  13
--r--r---r---r---r--- trunk
    \
     ----------------------- branch_test

Revision 10: added function1( ) to file A
Revision 12: added function2( ) to file A
```

This is  an image version of the above drawing: http://s22.postimg.org/hkzsavb35/SVN_diagram.png

I would like to copy revision 12 of files R, E, and A from trunk to branch_test. As if I would like a snapshop of those files at that stage, with all their content from previous revisions up to that date included. But only of those files involved in that revision.

- I don't want only the difference from revision 11 to 12. Because If I added a function1() to file A in r10, and a function2() to this same file A in r12, and I "cherry pick":

```
    cd branchWorkingCopy
    svn merge -c 12 ^/project/trunk
```

it will only upload the difference to the working copy, meaning function2() will be copied but function1() won't be there in the branch.

- I don't want the modifications for the Z file in revision 10, neither the modifications for the C file on revision 11. I just want what was the "current" whole file when r12 was commited, but only of those files involved in the commit. In this example I want file R, E and A with all their changes since revision 9. But I don't want to manually have to select file R, E and A.

Is there a way to to that in svn? Besides having to individually get all files and copy their latest revisions "by hand" (on an individual basis) ?

P.S.: What is the use case? Sometimes I'm ready/need to copy a modification (12) to our test branch, but I'm not yet ready to do it with a previous modification (r10), although I need some of the previous modification's updated files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an answer to your direct question: you will need to "cherry pick merge" each individual file. Luckly `svn merge` can act on individual files as well as on directory paths.

You *could* cherry-pick merge all revisions of interest and then revert the file changes you don't want, but then the merge info is wrong and a later merge will omit that revision even though there are more changes to apply.

But, the better question is, WHY do you need to get only part of a commit onto your branch in the first place? If you're using SVN efficiently, then each commit will only contain related changes which you will nearly always want all together, or not at all. Are you committing a bunch of unrelated changes together? If so, you should consider changing your development process instead of working around it.

Comment: You're right. I just came to realize that this indeed won't be good.

Suppose I have the following scenario:

revision10: FileA: Added function1(), added call to auxFunction() from FileUtil; FileUtil: added auxFunction();
    
revision 12:FileA: Added function2(); 

Now If I got what I requested, say revision12 with the "latest version" of all its files, I would be getting fileA with function1(), function2(), but also with a call to auxFunction(), which won't be there because, guess what, FileUtil wouldn't be included.

Comment: This could trigger all sorts of bugs, specially in non compiled code.

Thanks, I know have the resources to talk to the development team and change some mindsets. :)